# Django get cleaned data from MultipleChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms

I can´t find the way to get cleaned data from a MultipleChoiceField in a form.

I´m giving the user some options and then I want to concatenate the results in a string to compose the message body of an email.

**The form**

```
class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    contenidos_compartibles = (
        ('1', 'Catálogo x Marca'),
        ('2', 'Catálogo x Producto'),
        ('3', 'Lista de precios x Marca'),
        ('4', 'Lista de precios x Producto'),)

    incluir = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), choices=contenidos_compartibles, required=False)

    remitente = forms.EmailField()
    destinatario = forms.EmailField()
    cc = forms.EmailField(required=False)
    asunto = forms.CharField(required=False)
    mensaje = forms.CharField(required=False)    
    firma = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

**The view**

```
def SendEmailView(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        email_form = EmailForm(request.POST)

        if email_form.is_valid():
            mensaje = email_form.cleaned_data["mensaje"]
            adjuntos = email_form.cleaned_data["incluir"]

            for incluido in adjuntos:
                mensaje = mensaje + incluido
```

**The template**

```
<div class="container collapse" id="enviar_email" style="font-size: 14px; background-color: #e8ebef;">
<form style="margin-left: 1rem;" action="{% url 'send_email' %}" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 1rem;">
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div style="color: #0f0f0f;"><a style="">De: </a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <div style="">{{ email_form.remitente }}</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div style="padding-top: 1rem; color: #0f0f0f;"><a style="">Para</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <div style="padding-top: 1rem;">{{ email_form.destinatario }}</div>
                </div>
            </div>

             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div style="padding-top: 1rem; color: #0f0f0f;"><a style="">CC</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <div style="padding-top: 1rem;">{{ email_form.cc }}</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-2">
                    <div style="padding-top: 1rem; color: #0f0f0f;"><a style="">Incluir</a></div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-3">

                    <div class="btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons" style="padding-top: 1rem;">
                        {% for checkbox in email_form.incluir %}
                            <div class="btn btn-light btn-sm">
                                <a style="text-align: left;">{{ checkbox.choice_label }}</a>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>

        <div class="col">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div style="color: #0f0f0f;"><a style="">Asunto</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <div style="">{{ email_form.asunto }}</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div style="padding-top: 1rem; color: #0f0f0f;"><a style="">Mensaje</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <div style="padding-top: 1rem; height: 100px;">{{ email_form.mensaje }}</div>
                </div>
            </div>



        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="padding-bottom: 1rem; padding-top: 2rem;"><input style="" type="submit" value="Enviar" name="enviar_email"></div>



</form>

</div>
```

After sending the email I only get the original message but none of the options. It is supposed to be a simple list, but I can´t get it working and couldn´t get any clues on the webb.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you mean by *.....none of the **options*** ? options means the value of `contenidos_compartibles` variable?

Comment: Yes @JPG that´s what I mean. The options that the user chose.

Comment: I can access the selected choices from `email_form.cleaned_data["incluir"]` . Don't you?

Comment: No, that´s my issue. When I iterate over "adjuntos" as shown above I get no strings from the list.

Comment: did you click on any check-boxes in the form?

Comment: Hahahahah Yes I did!

Comment: Please post the template where you render that form.

Comment: @JPG Just updated the question with the template part.

Comment: @JPG I found the problem. I was missing the "checkbox.tag". Thanks for the guidance. Post the answer if you want so I can vote your answer.